# How to make visible hidden attributes in laravel queryBuilder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Im working on a laravel project which is using innertia, vue stack. In my project some models have hidden attributes. I want to make visible them in some routes. But i cant use makeVisible() with query builder. is there a solution for this?

***method in controller***

```php
    $hosters = Hoster::query()
            ->when($request->input('search'), function ($query, $search) {
                if ($search == "approved") {
                    return $query->where('is_approved', '=', true);
                } elseif ($search == "notapproved") {
                    return $query->where('is_approved', '=', false);
                }
                return $query
                    ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('contact_number', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            })
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(8)
            ->withQueryString();

        return Inertia::render('Hoster/Show', [
            'hosters' => $hosters,
            'filters' => $request->only(['search']),
        ]);
```

***hidden fields in model***

```php
    protected $hidden = [
        'past_works',
        'anchor',
        'contact_number',
        'email'
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `makeVisible` method

> The makeVisible method makes attributes visible that are typically
> "hidden" on each model in the collection

```
$hosters = Hoster::query()
            ->when($request->input('search'), function ($query, $search) {
                if ($search == "approved") {
                    return $query->where('is_approved', '=', true);
                } elseif ($search == "notapproved") {
                    return $query->where('is_approved', '=', false);
                }
                return $query
                    ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('contact_number', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            })
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(8)
            ->withQueryString();

    $hosters->makeVisible([
        'past_works'
    ]);

        return Inertia::render('Hoster/Show', [
            'hosters' => $hosters,
            'filters' => $request->only(['search']),
        ]);
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-makeVisible
Ref:https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16501

Comment: Note that return of `$hosters->makeVisible(['past_works']);` is an instance of **Collection** not **LengthAwarePaginator**